# How to match only numbers that do not have an alpha character in front/behind?

Tags: java, regex

I am fairly new to regex expressions. In Java, I am trying to find the pattern:

```
(<numeric> (completes|completing)) OR ((completes|completing) <numeric>)
```

The regex I am using is

```
([\d]*(.[\d]+))?\s*(completes|completing)\s*([\d]*(.[\d]+))?
```

It will match the following patterns:

```
2.29 completes
completes 2.29
2.29 completing
completing 2.29
```

However, the input text may have an alpha char next to the number. In these cases, The output would be:

```
x3.25 completes 2.29 (match: completes 2.29)
2.29 completes 3.25x (match: 2.29 completes)
x3.25 completing 2.29 (match: completing 2.29)
2.29 completing 3.25x (match: 2.29 completing)
```

Here is sample data

```
n16 2.00/2.50  stg live completes 6.5
v/f -30 cso   completing  .006
m16 1.95p live completing 1
m16 1.95p live completing 1 again and out
n16 1.75/2.50 stg live completing 2.6
v16 2.75c x2.39 completing 9.9, 650x go
v16 2.75c x2.39 completing 9.9 again, 900 go
q 2.0 p vs 2.25/2.50 cs live .026 completing
q 2.00 p vs 2.25/2.50 c 2.21 completes 500x .026
v16 2.75c x2.39 completing 9.9 again and out, 1500x go
m16 1.90p live completing .25 and out
fh17 4.00/4.50cs x3.01 completing 4.9
z 2.00 p x2.89 completes .023 6 delta
fh17 4.00/4.50cs x3.01 completing 4.9 again, 500/month go
h17  4.00/6.00 cs x 2.99  completes 12.4 ,  18  delta
h17  4.00/6.00 cs x 2.99  completes 12.4 , 18 delta , 500x , 12.3/12.5 follow
z 2.00 p x2.89 completes .024
fh17 4.00/4.50cs x3.01 completing 5 now
f17-h17 2.50/3.00 ps x 3.01  completes 23.3 , 21 delta
h17 5.00 c x 2.99 completes 8.7
cal18 2.25/4.25 fen live completing 1.2, 200/month go and out
```

How would the regex look to meet this requirement? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use word boundaries on each side : `\b\d+(?:.\d+)?\s*completes\s*\d+(?:.\d+)?\b`

Comment: Your information is incomplete. The only thing for sure is that it requires `completes`. Even if it matched a number (which is optional) the number requires a decimal in it. If this requires validation, you should use anchors to designate the start and end.

Comment: @anubhava missing \ in `.`

Comment: How much of this `3.25 completes 2.29` do you want to match?

Comment: @sln if the input was `today hedge x3.25 completes 2.29 price`, then I would only want to match `completes 2.29`

Comment: @sln excuse my ignorance, but what is an anchor? do you mean start/end of line?

Comment: Yeah anchors are begin/end of string, but there are pseudo anchor like boundaries. You still didn't answer my question, how much of `3.25 completes 2.29` do you want to match ?

Comment: Have to decide what to match before you can affix assertion boundary's. As it is now, you're regex will match `<num>completes<num>` _or_ `<num>completes` _or_ `completes<num>` _or_ `completes` As for number boundary's, have to decide what they look like, can it be just non alpha-num or what?

Comment: check **[this](https://regex101.com/r/pQ5dD7/1)**..

Comment: I just edited the question by adding more details

Comment: You didn't add any new details, it is _unclear_ as to what you're asking. It really doesn't matter about the alpha character at this point.

Comment: I suggest [`\p{L}+\d*\.?\d+|\d*\.?\d+\p{L}+|\b(?:(\d*\.?\d+)\s*(completes|completing)|(completes|completing)\s*(\d*\.?\d+)\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/fY2fR0/1), and get Group 1 & 2 or 3 & 4 (check can be done inside `while(m.find())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

`(?=x\s*[0-9.]+\s+complet).*?\K(?:complet(?:es|ing))\s*[0-9.]+|complet(?:es|ing)\s*[0-9.]+(?!\s*x|[0-9])|[0-9.]+\s*complet(?:es|ing)`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- will match `completes` or `completing` and the preceding or trailing number
- excludes the preceding number if the number is preceded by a `x`
- excludes the trailing number if it's followed by an `x`

Note: changed the assertion for numbers from `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9])?` which requires numbers with a single optional decimal point to `[0-9.]+` as it appears that your sample text is already validated and the format is easier to read.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/oA7fU4/1

**Sample text**

```
n16 2.00/2.50  stg live completes 6.5
v/f -30 cso   completing  .006
m16 1.95p live completing 1
m16 1.95p live completing 1 again and out
n16 1.75/2.50 stg live completing 2.6
v16 2.75c x2.39 completing 9.9, 650x go
v16 2.75c x2.39 completing 9.9 again, 900 go
q 2.0 p vs 2.25/2.50 cs live .026 completing
q 2.00 p vs 2.25/2.50 c 2.21 completes 500x .026
v16 2.75c x2.39 completing 9.9 again and out, 1500x go
m16 1.90p live completing .25 and out
fh17 4.00/4.50cs x3.01 completing 4.9
z 2.00 p x2.89 completes .023 6 delta
fh17 4.00/4.50cs x3.01 completing 4.9 again, 500/month go
h17  4.00/6.00 cs x 2.99  completes 12.4 ,  18  delta
h17  4.00/6.00 cs x 2.99  completes 12.4 , 18 delta , 500x , 12.3/12.5 follow
z 2.00 p x2.89 completes .024
fh17 4.00/4.50cs x3.01 completing 5 now
f17-h17 2.50/3.00 ps x 3.01  completes 23.3 , 21 delta
h17 5.00 c x 2.99 completes 8.7
cal18 2.25/4.25 fen live completing 1.2, 200/month go and out
```

**Sample Matches**

```
[0] => completes 6.5
[1] => completing  .006
[2] => completing 1
[3] => completing 1
[4] => completing 2.6
[5] => completing 9.9
[6] => completing 9.9
[7] => .026 completing
[8] => 2.21 completes
[9] => completing 9.9
[10] => completing .25
[11] => completing 4.9
[12] => completes .023
[13] => completing 4.9
[14] => completes 12.4
[15] => completes 12.4
[16] => completes .024
[17] => completing 5
[18] => completes 23.3
[19] => completes 8.7
[20] => completing 1.2
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    x                        'x'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9.]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', '.' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    complet                  'complet'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       'K'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    complet                  'complet'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      es                       'es'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ing                      'ing'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9.]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', '.' (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  complet                  'complet'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    es                       'es'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ing                      'ing'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9.]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', '.' (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    x                        'x'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9.]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', '.' (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  complet                  'complet'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    es                       'es'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ing                      'ing'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Wow very nice fiddle site. I am playing around with it now. I just updated my question with more detail.

Comment: TY. I've overhauled my answer to resolve the additional sample text added to your question. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yea this is the answer. I am just going over the explanation on the fiddle to learn. Wow thanks